# When scrolling down on a website in Firefox, the scrolling stops when the cursor is over an animated element

Tags: reactjs, animation, firefox, svg, gsap

Ok so I built this website here: https://savvasnicholas.com. Everything was working totally fine in all browsers except I noticed some very odd behaviour in Firefox. When I load the page, I can't scroll down.

I have heavily used animations in this page with GSAP. The source code is here: https://github.com/iamyojimbo/savvasnicholas

Upon further investigation, it seems that I can indeed scroll down, but the scrolling stops short when my cursor is not positioned over an element that animates. So, if I position my cursor in the scroll gutter to the outside or even in the padding of the main content container, I can scroll up and down freely, until I hover my cursor over an animated element again.

Odd!

I have tried disabling "smooth scrolling" with no effect and also Googling. Either I've done something stupid and have a weird browser or overflow setting on or this would seem like a very intense Firefox bug!

If anyone has any idea what's going on here, I would be most grateful!

Comment: pointer-events: none on that element causing the problem.

Comment: Probably one of your components are listening to scroll event to start the animation and calling `preventDefaul()` or `stopPropagation()` and preventing your scroll to go on

Comment: @RobertLongson are you referring to the logo?

Comment: @iamyojimbo I've no idea, I never follow links in questions so if you want me to comment on something you'd need to put it in the question itself. You should add a [mcve] to the question really.